# How can I compare 2 tables in mysql and check the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two tables, one of them is for friends of a person and another one is for channel member.

I want to check if one of my friends is one of the channel members. If so don't show his name, else show him.

```
$get_friend = "select * from friends where user_1_id='$user_id' AND friends_status=1";
$run_friend = mysqli_query($conn,$get_friend);

$select_members = "SELECT user_id from channel_members where channel_id='$channel_id'";
$run_members = mysqli_query($conn,$select_members);
```

Comment: Can you explain your tables a little? What is the name  of the column in your friends table called in which the userid of the friend is?

Comment: yes in friends table I have 3 column user_1_id , user_2_id, friends_status

Comment: actually I want to add friends in a channel and I want to compare if a  user already added to channel then dont add them again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query :

```
select * from friends where user_1_id='$user_id' AND friends_status=1 AND user_2_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id from channel_members where channel_id='$channel_id')
```

This will select all your friends from friends table which are not a member of channel '$channel_id'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    friends.*
FROM
    friends
LEFT JOIN channel_members 
    ON channel_members.channel_id = '$channel_id' 
        AND channel_members.user_id = friends.user_2_id
WHERE
    user_1_id = '$user_id' 
        AND friends_status = 1 
        AND channel_members.channel_id IS NULL
```

You can use this query.

I added an excluding `LEFT JOIN`.

It will try to join the members of the channel who are your friends to the result, but by specifying `channel_members.channel_id IS NULL` in the where clause you are filtering those datasets out which really have a member in the channel - leaving you with only the friends who are not in the channel.

Comment: thank you my friend I will test it and then answer the result